# Google Cloud App Engine Standard deployment with PHP 7.4 / 8.1 mongodb extension not working

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I have already successfully deployed the app in php standard 7.4 environment and its running, today i wanted to update it and when i do gcloud app deploy i get:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-mongodb * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
Problem 2
    - mongodb/mongodb is locked to version 1.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
```

So i checked the php.ini file for the deployment, its in the root folder (same level as the yaml file) and contains:

```
extension=mongodb.so
extension=redis.so
extension=igbinary.so
```

Did i missed any google cloud update? I am wondering cause it does not complain about the version of the mongodb php extension and just says there is no extension?

I also tried to switch to PHP 8.1 runtime but i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
"provide" : {
    "ext-mongo": "*"
},
```

i was able to fix it by adding this to my composer.json .. somehow i never needed it until today.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me adding to composer.json, so *ext-mongodb* instead of *ext-mongo* (I cannot comment on the answer of [user1334817](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334817/user1334817) )

```
"provide" : {
    "ext-mongodb": "*"
}
```